# Trying to filter a mysql table by date using a single query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to request any records from a table that appear on or after today's date, using a single query.
All the dates for each record are stored in separate columns e.g.. - one for `month`, one for `year`, and one for `day`.

obviously i've been getting all records that occur after the year in today's date

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE year>=".$year_today." 
       ORDER BY year, month, day";
```

Then i've been trying to filter that down a bit, by using:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table 
        WHERE year>=".$year_today." && month>=".$month_today." 
              && day>=".$day_today." 
        ORDER BY year, month, day";
```

And in order to test it, i created a record in the database with **yesterdays** date, yet, this record still appears in the list of returned records. What am i doing wrong? :(

Comment: Why are you using 3 columns instead of one DATE typed column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can use "&&" instead of "AND" in your context - maybe try changing your SQL to use

```
" AND month>=".$month_today." AND day>=".$day_today."
```

### EDIT :

as an extension to Nick's answer, to make the sql behave correctly you could code :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (  
(year>".$year_today.")
OR (year=".$year_today." && month>".$month_today." )
OR (year=".$year_today." && month=".$month_today."&& day>=".$day_today.")
)
 ORDER BY year, month, day";
```

...but this starts to get a whole lot messier than converting to dates and using date comparison

### EDIT2:

but then again, if these columns are indexed, the indexes might be used. It's still a lot more effort to code SQL this way if performance using conversion to dates is totally acceptable.

Comment: The mysql documentation claims that AND and && are equivalent

Comment: fair enough, I learn something every day. Two things some days.

Comment: @Steve: Actually my first thought was the same as yours - maybe && is different than AND.  I had just finished checking the mysql docs when your comment came up :)

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved using time functions in a nice way, while it's better when using a DATE column.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(year,"-",month,"-",day)) >= CURDATE()
```

ok, that's evil as it doesn't use an index ... proper thing would be a DATE column, but doing all this by hand is annoying asyou also have to consider the case where year is bigger but months is smaller and stuff ....

Answer (score 1):

To compare dates with dates:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
  STR_TO_DATE(
    CONCAT(year
    , '-'
    , right(concat('00', month), 2)
    , '-'
    , right(concat('00', day), 2))
  , '%Y-%m-%d')

>= STR_TO_DATE('2009-12-11', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

to check if a date is after another date this query will fail:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE year>=".$year_today." && month>=".$month_today." && day>=".$day_today." ORDER BY year, month, day";
```

day 12 march of februari is smaller then day 15 in februari, but is still after it, because it's in a different month....

Comment: Are you sure february is after march ?

Comment: While February is not after March... his point is valid.  The logic of the original question doesn't make sense because it requires that the month, day, and year all be numerically greater.